# Trailing 0 decimal after casting to string to float

Tags: amazon-redshift

In redshift I'm trying to convert a string to a float and round to 2 decimal places. But when I do that I get a lot of trailing 0's at at the end.

```
select 
'1.99'
, '1.99'::float
, round('1.99'::float , 2)
```

Seems like the round function doesn't do anything.
I want to just get 1.99 as a float and not 1.9900000000000

I'm using DBeaver btw

Answer (score 1):

I think its just the format you see using your client software that is the issue here.

if you DO want to reformat it inside your sql (to 1.99) then you could use to_char like this.

```
select to_char('1.99'::float,'99999D99');
```

Answer (score 0):

In most languages, round() alters the *value* not the length of a number.

Looks to me like you need to use trunc() instead or possibly as well.

See: [Redshift docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRUNC.html)