# Redshift SQL cast giving unexpected decimal value

Tags: amazon-redshift

In Redshift, I have a table `t` with float8 column `length` of value 16.7 and float8 column `width` of value 10.

I'd like to create a new column `dimension` with value `10X16.7`.

However,

```
select width::varchar + 'X' + length::varchar
from t
```

gives `10X16.699999999999999`.

Rounding does not help:

```
select width, length, round(length, 1), width::varchar + 'X' + length::varchar, width::varchar + 'X' + round(length, 1)::varchar
from t
```

gives

```
10.0    16.7    16.7    10X16.699999999999999   10X16.699999999999999
```

The `TO_CHAR` function gets me close (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56398693/11262633), but the SQL below gives an unwanted `.` next to the `10`:

```
SELECT to_char(width, 'FM99D9') + 'X' + to_char("length", 'FM99D9')
from t
```

gives

```
10.X16.7
```

Also, sometimes my `length` column does not have a decimal point, and in that case I don't want to show one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast the length value as a DECIMAL and then use concat to achieve the desired within a subquery.

```sql
drop table if exists concat_test;
create table concat_test
(length float8,
width float8);

insert into concat_test values (16.7, 10);
insert into concat_test values (16, 10);




select 
        length || 'X' || width as Dimensions FROM
        (select
    case
        when position('.' in length) > 0 then length::DECIMAL(5,
        1)::VARCHAR
        else length::VARCHAR end as length, width::VARCHAR
    from
        concat_test) TBL;
```

#### RESULT:

| dimensions |
| --- |
| 16.7X10 |
| 16X10 |

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of floating point numbers.  These are represented after the decimal point by binary digits that represent 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, etc.  .7 doesn't translate well into this format so you get .699999999999999 when this binary value is translated back to decimal.  So the "unexpected decimal value" is explainable.

I expect you will want to cast this float to decimal and then to text.  If this doesn't resolve the "not wanting .0" issue, I think it will, you will need to massage the result to what you want.